# Assigning the result of an across(starts_with(), mean) to the R dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, summarize, across

Instead of writing manually an average of

```
df$average<- (df$a + df$b + df$c)/3
```

I wanted to use across, but I can't manage to attach it because then creates a 1x1 dataframe
I was trying variations of this without success.

```
df$`mean trust` <- df%>% 
    summarise(across(starts_with("Trust"), mean, na.rm = TRUE))
```

and also

```
df$`mean trust` <- df%>%
  summarise(across(starts_with("Trust"), 
                   mean, na.rm=TRUE,
                   .names = "`mean trust`"))
```

I also prefer to use %<>% to assign, if that's possible at all. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `rowMeans` and instead of `summarise`, it would be `mutate`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
     mutate(meantrust = select(., starts_with("Trust")) %>%
                     rowMeans( na.rm = TRUE))
```

---

With `c_across`, we can use `mean` (but it is not vectorized)

```
df %>%
    rowwise %>% 
    mutate(meantrust = mean(c_across(starts_with("Trust")), na.rm = TRUE))
```

A reproducible example with `iris`

```
data(iris)
head(iris) %>%
    rowwise %>%
     mutate(meanSepal = mean(c_across(starts_with("Sepal")), na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: Every time I think about using `c_across` it just seems like such a waste of resources. I'm not sure it's a valuable addition to `dplyr`. +1